# Mapping IntPtr into Struct via Marshal.PtrToStructure causing "Access Violation Exception"

Tags: c#, exception, marshalling, access-violation, intptr

I'm trying to use a C++ DLL (3rd party library implementing EMI protocol, having source code available) in .NET. I've succesfully done marshalling, calling the functions and getting everything work fine.

The problem occurs when I want to do marshalling from IntPtr back into the .NET Struct , here's the code (modified as suggested - removed "ref" and changed the AllocHGlobal to allocate just size of emiStruct) :

```
private EMI emiStruct;
private IntPtr emiIntPtr;

emiIntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(emiStruct));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(emiStruct, emiIntPtr, false);
EMIStruct.Error result = emi_init(emiIntPtr, hostname, portNumber, password, shortNumber, windowSize, throughput);
Marshal.PtrToStructure(emiIntPtr, emiStruct);
```

The last line (PtrToStructure) causes an exception "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt".

Also, I can see a debug output:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
First-chance exception at 0x7c970441 in XXXXX.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xc3fffff8.
First-chance exception at 0x7c970441 in XXXXX.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x01fffff7.
First-chance exception at 0x7c970441 in XXXXX.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00001f1d.
```

I assume the problem is somewhere in allocation of memory for the pointer emiIntPtr. Althought, when I run the code, and there is a problem with connecting to the server (e.g. server not found), the followed marshalling to the Struct emiStruct is done correctly (no exception). The problem only occurs when the connection is succesfully established and server send a respond.

Also, I wrote a C++ sample app using the same DLL library I'm trying to use in .NET, and this application (when I compile it) runs just fine - it means, the C++ DLL should be ok and not causing crashing.

Furthermore, I've found some hints to check/uncheck several properties for the project compilator (using JIT, compile it for x86 cpu, etc.), unfortunately, none of this helped.

Do you have any suggestion where the problem might be or how to do a correct IntPtr inicialization in .NET and mapping between IntPtr and Struct?

Thanks all for your replies:

Here I'm adding the C++ header of the emi_init func:

```
FUNC( init)( EMI*           emi,         /* out */
const char*    hostname,    /* in  */
unsigned short port,        /* in  */
const char*    password,    /* in  */
const char*    origin_addr, /* in  */
int            window_sz,   /* in  */
         int            throughput); /* in  */
```

And here is the C# emi_init declaration (I've removed the "ref" attribute for emiPtr as was suggested):

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("emi.dll", EntryPoint = "_emi_init")]
    public static extern EMIStruct.Error emi_init(
    System.IntPtr emiPtr,
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()]  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string hostname,
    ushort port,
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()] [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string password,
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()] [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string origin_addr,
    int window_sz, int throughput);
```

However, still getting the same exception.

Comment: why are you passing the ptr by ref? That seems odd. Would be good to see the c++ headers.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Interesting spot :)

Comment: @frankie Why won't you show us the C++ side of the interface?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Marshal.PtrToStructure` incorrectly.

The second argument requires a type, iow `typeof(EMI)`.

The return value contains the resulting struct.

So the solution should be:

```
var s = (EMI) Marshal.PtrToStructure(emiIntPtr, typeof(EMI));
```

Comment: I also had it like that before but with no success. I've just tried it with your suggested syntax but still getting the same exception :(

Comment: Try allocating only a single 'instance' not a range of 100000.

Comment: @leppie There are two overloads and frankie is using the other one.

Comment: @David Heffernan: You cannot use a boxed value type on that overload, see the docs. You can however use a sequential or fixed layout reference type for that overload.

Comment: @leppie Clearly that overload is fine since the code compiles.

Comment: @David Heffernan: That is the most naive thing I have heard in months!

Comment: @David Heffernan: In case you missed it, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30ex8z62 , specifically the Remarks section. Last sentence.

Comment: @leppie Why? The compiler can check all the requirements you state and presumably does so. That's all I meant. This would all be a lot easier if Frankie showed us the C++!

Comment: @David Heffernan: That's what the docs say! Dont kill the messenger :) I dont even know why he is using this approach. A ref struct or unsafe would be much better.

Comment: That doc seems contradictory? Can't use it with a value type, but can use it with a sequential or explicit structure. I'm no expert with .net and assume that compiler would deal with this. If use of this overload was the real problem, why would the error be AV?

Comment: @David Heffernan: I can only assume some required COM functionality.

Comment: ref struct sounds good to me too. Who knows what's really going on here?!

Comment: @David Heffernan: As for the AV, that would be many things. Most likely the size of the native and managed structs do not match.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have declared the first parameter incorrectly in the C#. You have declared it as ref IntPtr which is equivalent to EMI** in C++. But I bet the C++ declaration, which you unfortunately did not include, reads EMI*. So simply remove the ref and all should be well.

I expect that emi_init does not read from the EMI parameter, i.e. it has out semantics. In which case you don't need the StructureToPtr call before you call emi_init.